# fabricjs cloned object affect old(default) object

Tags: clone, fabricjs

I am trying to get shadow Image of Text object without affecting the output of fabric.

Code

```
var clonedText = jQuery.extend({}, obj);
clonedText.fill = "rgba(50,50,50,0.5)";
imageURL = clonedText.toDataURL({format:'png'});
```

Result

Default:[image]
AfterRun:[image]

How can it be fixed?
I mean how can I copy object so that cant affect default image?

UPDATE:

I also tried this and this.

```
canvas._objects.forEach(function(obj, index){
 var clonedText = fabric.util.object.clone(obj);
    clonedText.fill = "rgba(50,50,50,0.5)";
    imageURL = clonedText.toDataURL({format:'png'});
});
```

This has same result.

Comment: which version of fabricjs you are using?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi can you check this [issue](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/qn066wtz/) after getting `toDataURL` of a cloned object it affects to parent element as well, after scaling it comes back to original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should not really clone instances like you would clone javascript objects.
Fabric objects can have references to canvas elements, image elements, deep structures, and every clone logic works on its own.

on fabricjs docs is specified that fabric.util.object.extende/clone does not clones fabricJS objects:

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.object.html

Also in the docs is specified the clone method:

[image]

So you have to run

```
myText.clone(function(cloned) {
  // do something with cloned....
});
```

If you are in need of a full syncronous process, and you are not using patterns or image sources for text you can also do:

```
var objectForm = myText.toObject();
var clonedText = new fabric.Text(objectForm.text, objectForm);
```